# Why can't I download zip-file in my php model if acces it from ajax script. Works fine from php link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, zip

I have links to a number of images (my object contains the links). I want to download all these images in a zip file. I started with this code which works well.

Download link in the view (to my controller)

```
<a href="<?php echo URL . 'album/downloadImage/' ?>" id="disableButton" class="download-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>Download all photos</a>
```

My controller

```
public function downloadImage()
{
    $this->model->downloadImage();
}
```

And my model. The model will automatically start downloading a zip file containing images

```
public function downloadImage() {
  $imageNumber = 1;
  $zipName = 'name-'.date("Y-m-d").'.zip';

  # create new zip opbject
  $zip = new ZipArchive();

  # create a temp file & open it
  $tmp_file = tempnam('.','');
  $zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

  # loop through each file
  foreach($this->imageUrl as $file){
      # Get extension
      $ext = pathinfo(parse_url($file->url, PHP_URL_PATH), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

      # download file
      $download_file = file_get_contents($file->url);

      # add it to the zip
      $zip->addFromString(basename($imageNumber.'-name.'.$ext),$download_file);

      $imageNumber++;
  }

    # close zip
    $zip->close();

    # send the file to the browser as a download
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipName);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($tmp_file));
    readfile($tmp_file);
```

}

This code works fine but because I want to modify the html tags during and after the download I want to make the call through ajax instead.

Updated my view link to

```
<a href="#" id="disableButton" class="download-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>Download all photos</a>
```

And added this to my .js-file

```
if ($('#disableButton').length !== 0) {
    $('#disableButton').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax(url + "album/downloadImage")
            .done(function(result) {
                //done
            })
            .fail(function() {
                // this will be executed if the ajax-call had failed
            })
            .always(function() {
                // this will ALWAYS be executed, regardless if the ajax-call was success or not
            });
    });
}
```

All other code is the same. I have tested log in my controller and model function and I access them but my download will not start.

Why does not the download of the zip file start if I call through my ajax function but works if I make it through php in my html link. Receive no error message.

Answer (score -1):

Use [jQuery File Download Plugin](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/) for this.
It's really very simple:

```
$.fileDownload('some/file.pdf')
.done(function () { alert('File download a success!'); })
.fail(function () { alert('File download failed!'); });
```

Comment: Will this help me to be able to download all the images as a zip in my model ? should I change $.fileDownload('some/file.pdf') to $.fileDownload('url + "album/downloadImage') which is the path to my controller.